# MongoDB - Remove duplicates in query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have to work with MongoDB for my job, but I'm not very comfortable with it. I have to gather some documents and remove duplicates according to one field.

Here is a (very very) simplified structure of a document :

```
{
    'user': 'The User',
    'report': {
        'id' : 0
        ...
    }
}
```

A **user** can have *several* **reports**, and *several identical* **reports** (not a conception mistake, only the simplified structure makes it strange).

A **report** is only related to *one* **user**.

I would like to retrieve a set of Reports-User by removing all duplicates reports id. Here is an example :

```
# Datas

User    | Report ID
--------|----------
User1   | AAAA
User1   | AAAA
User1   | BBBB
User2   | CCCC
User3   | DDDD
User3   | DDDD
```

```
# Excepted output where each line represents a document

User    | Report ID
--------|----------
User1   | AAAA
User1   | BBBB
User2   | CCCC
User3   | DDDD
```

I am really confused with all the aggregators. How can I do this?

Comment: See if this post is helpful: [Remove duplicates from MongoDB 4.2 data base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58409232/remove-duplicates-from-mongodb-4-2-data-base/58414376#58414376).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward using the `$group` operator in aggregation pipeline.

First, my sample data:

```
[
    { 'user': 'User1', report: { id: 'AAAA' } },
    { 'user': 'User1', report: { id: 'BBBB' } },
    { 'user': 'User1', report: { id: 'AAAA' } },
    { 'user': 'User2', report: { id: 'CCCC' } },
    { 'user': 'User3', report: { id: 'DDDD' } },
    { 'user': 'User3', report: { id: 'DDDD' } }
]
```

To get the same Expected format you posted, you can execute the following query:

```js
db.reports.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$report.id",
            user: {
                $first: '$user'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            User: '$user',
            Report: '$_id'
        }
    }
])
```

The first step in this aggregation pipeline groups all of the items in your collection by `report.id`.  Notice the dot notation to reference a field the embedded document.  It also projects the `user` field by selecting the value of the `user` field on the first document mongo finds with that report ID.  You mention that report IDs are unique to users, so this shouldn't cause any problems.

The second step in this aggregation pipeline just renames the fields to the names you used for your expected format.  The `$group` operator sets the `_id` field of the output to the field you grouped by (in this case, `report.id`).  The `$project` command uses that value to set the `Report` field and unsets the `_id`.